# Changing the Position of a button inside a Picturebox

Tags: c#, forms, position, controls

Im currently tryng to make a checker program using c# and windows forms.
I sorted out how to make a checker box using the PictureBox Object and how to use rounded Buttons as dimes. The catch is that unless I make the dimes with the exact height and whidt as the checker the dime gets positioned on the upper-left side of the Picturebox.
I wanted to ask if anyone knew a way to change the position of the dime(basically center it to the picturebox) so that it looks prettier.

This is the code i use to generate the box and add the dimes to the first 3 lines of the board(Im not putting them in the last 3 still just for the sake of comodity)

```
This is the code i use to generate the box and add the dimes to the first 3 lines of the board(Im not putting them in the last 3 still just for the sake of comodity)

for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
                {
                    PictureBox casella = new PictureBox();
                    casella.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    casella.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    casella.Height = flpScacchiera.Height / 8;
                    casella.Width = flpScacchiera.Width / 8;
                    if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1 || x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        casella.BackColor = Color.Black;
                        if (y < 3)
                        {
                            Button p = GeneraPedina();
                            p.Height = casella.Height;
                            p.Width = casella.Width;
                            p.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                            p.Parent = casella;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        casella.BackColor = Color.Khaki;
                    //aggiungo la casella alla matrice, questo mi permetterà di accedere a qualsiasi casella specifica in qualsiasi momento
                    scacchiera[x, y] = casella;
                    flpScacchiera.Controls.Add(casella);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do but I would put some parenteshis in this condition so as to make it more clear: if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0))

Comment: You are setting p.Height and p.Width. Isn't it missing to be set p.Left and p.Top ?

Comment: @MundoPeter that basically draws the board and the condition determines wich color should the checker be. I'll try to use those properties tho thank you for the advice